# Website is accessible using HTTPS but cannot access it when using HTTP

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Hi stackoverflow community, I have a website that is accessible using HTTPS, however when you try to access it using HTTP it says that "This site can’t be reached". The problem is when a new visitor is trying to reach my website and did not enter https://siteurl they will not be able to view my website.

Here are some details.

1. The website is hosted on an ubuntu server.
2. Using Apache as my http server
3. SSL certificate is installed.
4. Checked my server's firewall(all good).

Configuration files:
.htaccess

```
>RewriteEngine on <br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} siteurl [NC]<br>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 <br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://siteurl/$1 [R=301,L]<br>

><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L

</IfModule>
```

## Bitnami Configuration

```
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
 NameVirtualHost *:80
 NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion><br>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName siteurl 
 Redirect / https://siteurl/
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256<br> EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName siteurl
 
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
SSLEngine on<br>
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/OV_intermediate.crt"

            
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
        
  
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>


Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Comment: If you ssh into the server and wget localhost, do you still get 404?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} siteurl [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://siteurl/$1 [R=301,L]` is this okay? try using empty htacess

Comment: @Martheen the result of wget show im connected , show 200
[link]https://imageupload.io/gcTg5ONEtw.i

Comment: If this is a cloud server, maybe it's still blocked by the VPC firewall rules (unrelated to the OS firewall)

Comment: Not really a solution (the correct solution will be fixing whatever block port 80 either on OS/router/VPC), but if the site uses HSTS, submitted to the HSTS preload list and the user has updated their browser, the browser will never attempt to connect to port 80 and automatically use HTTPS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wonder if the `<br>` entries are there in the conf file or if it's something that got inserted when pasting it in your post?
(I'm not familiar with how wordpress works). Edit to clarify: They should not be a part of the configuration file (unless it is something specific to a hosting env. and how it interprets pasted config, or if it's something specific to wordpress that I'm not aware of, but I doubt it).

Second: You can test your config using either `apachectl configtest` or `httpd -t` to verify that you don't have any syntax errors that is causing unexpected behavior.

Third, I would suggest looking into the hosting site (if you're using some hosting service), if they allow http on port 80 at all in their firewall or if it's blocked there, like Martheen suggested above.

Comment: i have edited my post , the <br> entries is not included in the conf files, i have test my configuration with apachectl configtest and result shows syntax OK. I would be looking in to your third suggestion, but im not sure how to look at amazon lightsail firewall. But I will be checking at this.

Comment: Check this out, you might need to create a firewall rule that allows traffic on port 80: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail#creating-firewall-rules